# Jump to line from console view in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Running tests in `PhpStorm` I get links to files with line numbers which doesn't work for me on `windows 10`.
I could swear it did work but now it doesn't
[image]

Comment: I think the best place to report/complain/ask for solutions is the [JetBrain's bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues).

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall PhpStorm, looks like file association is broken.